# WebSetup Installer not getting CustomDataAction values

Tags: installation, setup-project, windows-installer

I have a websetup package where I am using CustomActionData for the connection string. I have the following parameter setup in my "Primary output" node under Install and Commit for my installer:

```
/ConnectionString=[CONNECTIONSTRING]
```

My Installer class accepts this value as follows:

```
string connectionString = context.Parameters["ConnectionString"];
```

However when I execute msiexec as follows:

```
msiexec /i WebTestInstaller.msi ConnectionString="test" /quiet
```

The "context" object above never gets the "test" value. The "connectionstring" array variable is always empty.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this command line:

```
msiexec /i WebTestInstaller.msi CONNECTIONSTRING="test" /quiet
```

You are setting the installer property, not the parameter. During install the parameter uses the property value.